# Identifier 'Buffer' has already been declared

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, socket.io

**Identifier 'Buffer' has already been declared**

I'm trying to create a Video chat website using socket.io and react.js, but it gives me this an error in /~/src/App.js (15:39). Why does this occurs?

When I comment the code `const callUser` to `const leaveCall`, then it works fine and this error is gone and shows the result, but after uncommenting then it shows me this error again.

**This Is my code **

```
const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000')
function App() {
    const [ me, setMe ] = useState("")
    const [ stream, setStream ] = useState()
    const [ receivingCall, setReceivingCall ] = useState(false)
    const [ caller, setCaller ] = useState("")
    const [ callerSignal, setCallerSignal ] = useState()
    const [ callAccepted, setCallAccepted ] = useState(false)
    const [ idToCall, setIdToCall ] = useState("")
    const [ callEnded, setCallEnded] = useState(false)
    const [ name, setName ] = useState("")
    const myVideo = useRef()
    const userVideo = useRef()
    const connectionRef= useRef()
    useEffect(() => {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true }).then((stream) => {
            setStream(stream)
                myVideo.current.srcObject = stream
        })

    socket.on("me", (id) => {
            setMe(id)
        })

        socket.on("callUser", (data) => {
            setReceivingCall(true)
            setCaller(data.from)
            setName(data.name)
            setCallerSignal(data.signal)
        })
    }, [])
```

When I add this, the error occurs:

```
    const callUser = (id) => {
        const peer = new Peer({
            initiator: true,
            trickle: false,
            stream: stream
        })
        peer.on("signal", (data) => {
            socket.emit("callUser", {
                userToCall: id,
                signalData: data,
                from: me,
                name: name
            })
        })
        peer.on("stream", (stream) => {
            
                userVideo.current.srcObject = stream
            
        })
        socket.on("callAccepted", (signal) => {
            setCallAccepted(true)
            peer.signal(signal)
        })

        connectionRef.current = peer
    }

    const answerCall =() =>  {
        setCallAccepted(true)
        const peer = new Peer({
            initiator: false,
            trickle: false,
            stream: stream
        })
        peer.on("signal", (data) => {
            socket.emit("answerCall", { signal: data, to: caller })
        })
        peer.on("stream", (stream) => {
            userVideo.current.srcObject = stream
        })

        peer.signal(callerSignal)
        connectionRef.current = peer
    }

    const leaveCall = () => {
        setCallEnded(true)
        connectionRef.current.destroy()
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any mention of `Buffer` in this code

Comment: Yes, but why it show this error?